# htlatex failing with custom documentclass: Error LaTeX Error: File `email' not found

Tags: documentclass-writing, htlatex

I have created a custom class for a personal curriculum. It can be found at

https://github.com/igormorgado/elegantcv

It compiles nicely with pdlatex, XeTeX and LuaLaTeX, but trying to build with `htlatex` it fails with error:

`Error LaTeX Error: File 'email' not found`

I don't know enough to debug or build a MWE that raises the same error (have tried). Removing all references to my custom class, removes the error but that isn't a real MWE for the issue itself.

What I'm asking is:

1. How to correctly debug to be able to understand the error and be able to correctly point to the problem (and maybe fix by myself);
2. How to build a pristine well written, custom document class that allows me to run also with htlatex and do not raise warnings or errors.
3. How to solve this issue and be able to build a html version of my latex class.

To reproduce the issue just (assuming Unix)

```
git clone https://github.com/igormorgado/elegantcv
cd elegantcv
make html
```

PS: I know that create external references isn't the best way to handle SO question, but it would be better paste the whole class here? If so. I  can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got another error with the sample file in your repo, it was caused by the table. The issue is that Memoir, which you use as the base class, defines `\cmidrule` and other commands from the Booktabs package directly, instead of requiring the the package. Because of that, `tex4ht` cannot load patched versions of these commands and compilation error happens. I've fixed that in the `tex4ht` sources, so it shouldn't happen in the future. The problem is that TeX Live is currently frozen, so the fix will be included only in TL 2019.

In the meantime you can use the following configuration file, `elegantcv.4ht`:

```
\input booktabs.4ht
\Hinput{elegantcv}
\endinput
```

The line `\input booktabs.4ht` needs to be removed once TL2019 is released, because it would clash with the code in `memoir.4ht`.

It is possible to put other stuff in the `elegantcv.4ht` file, for example redefine macros from your class to insert HTML code. You can put the tags directly here, or, better in a configuration file. See my [tutorial for details](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial). I would surely add some CSS styling.

This is how it looks out of the box:

[image]

Comment: Nice! I had noticed that issue, but I thought it was completely unrelated. It has worked. Thanks for pointing out your tutorials. I will read them. Also It would be nice to learn about to set some CSS stylish based on my custom commands.

Comment: Just to add, I noticed that 2 hlines where created before and after the table, also, the hbar (created by cmidrule) do not looklike their memoir counterpart. Should I: a. moveout from memoir and use standard article; b. create custom CSS configuration ?; or c. wait for a fix somewhere else?

Comment: @Lin it is best to create HTML markup for your commands and then use the `\Css` commands for styling them. You can also include external CSS for overall design (colors, margins, fonts, etc.) using `\Configure{AddCss}{filename.css}`.

Comment: @Lin you may need several compilation steps to get the hlines correctly. but you are right that especially the cline doesn't look right. It may be best to fix that using CSS. each element in the table has unique id attribute, so it is possible to fix style them directly.